# Facebook 'LIKE' button for my fan page

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, web-deployment

I have a website that I want to add a like button to my facebook "fan page" (of the website). 
how can I do it?

I opend a draft html page on my pc just to check that it works and I cant see nothing.
I copied the basic SDK script right after the 'body' tag. 
and then the rest from this page.

```
<html>
```

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '666',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>





<script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=458066304313544";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your link from here : it easy 
[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/‎](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/%E2%80%8E)

Comment: tnx. solved the problem 
now when i click on the like button i get an error and a little windoe pops with the message: "Message Failed: This message contains content that has been blocked by our security systems."

Comment: i think this error come because , you are try your page from localhost

Comment: that's right
i uploaded the code on my website and it works fine! :D 
thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: worked. i opened the file on a server and not on a draft html file on my desktop :)

Comment: when i click the like button it gives me an error
"Message Failed: This message contains content that has been blocked by our security systems."

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code and change the bold line **"YOUR FACEBOOK PAGE URL"** to ur page url i.e., "http://facebook.com/mypage" leaving no spaces

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR FACEBOOK PAGE URL&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: still cant see the button.

Comment: @Kar19 It Work's might be somewhere you missed some line 

Check live demo of my code here for Proof mate 

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9yg9/

Comment: I tried it on local and that's why it didn't work. but now i have a new problem. 
when i click the like button it gives me an error "Message Failed: This message contains content that has been blocked by our security systems."